# How to prevent users from deleting their accounts?

Tags: plugin-development, users, customization

I'd like to prevent user from deleting his/her account. This is mainly because of our internal rules requiring either two users being deleted at once or none at all. The only way to delete accounts would be to contact administrator, who would do that from a special interface in the cockpit.

I have a custom plugin driving our installation of Wordpress, so I may wrote custom code to achieve this behavior.

Comment: And what exactly are you having problems with?

Comment: Also... How can you recognize these users? By role?

Comment: @kero, Users after logging in now can go to settings and choose to remove their accounts, I'd like either to remove this option, to show a message to contact admin instead or - in the worst case scenario, the least user friendly - interrupt the deleting process.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Hej, Doodge ;) In general it may work for all users, including admins. It should be possible though from the cockpit, so interrupting the deleting process most likely is not an option (at least not as-is)